# JSHint unable to find/interpret .jshintrc file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, webstorm, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I am using [WebStorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and created my angularJS project. I am also using `grunt`, and am using `grunt-contrib-jshint`. I had some options preconfigured in my `.jshintrc` file which were already in the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) repository I used to create the project:

```
{
  "strict": "global",
  "node": true,
  "globals": {
    // Angular
    "angular": false,

    // Angular mocks
    "module": false,
    "inject": false,

    // Jasmine
    "jasmine": false,
    "describe": false,
    "beforeEach": false,
    "afterEach": false,
    "it": false,
    "expect": false,

    // Protractor
    "browser": false,
    "element": false,
    "by": false
  }
}
```

When I run `grunt jshint` on terminal, I get many errors, all of them related to the errors which arise when options are not set properly. However, when I copy these options and put them in my `Gruntfile`, everything works like a charm.

```
 jshint: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
        options: {
            // options here to override JSHint defaults
            node: true,
            globals: {
                // Angular
                angular: false,

                // Angular mocks
                module: false,
                inject: false,

                // Jasmine
                jasmine: false,
                describe: false,
                beforeEach: false,
                afterEach: false,
                it: false,
                expect: false,

                // Protractor
                browser: false,
                element: false,
                by: false
            }
        }
    },
```

Basically, what I've understood is `jshint` is not reading options from the `.jshintrc` file. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option [`jshintrc`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#jshintrc) for your `jshint` task to `true`.

> If set to true, no config will be sent to JSHint and JSHint will search for .jshintrc files relative to the files being linted.

Comment: Not working, I set my `jshint` task to:
`jshint: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
            jshintrc: true}`
,did not work.

Comment: You should set the option in the `options` section.

Comment: Thanks. Works, like a charm again! :)